# Maximum number of databases supported by SQL Server 2014 editions

Tags: sql-server

Looking for a straight forward answer from the SQL guru's

To make a decision on which license to purchase, we were looking for the number of databases supported by a server instance of each edition (Express, Web, Standard, Enterprise) but couldn't find any useful information on the net. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @ughai so this is not limited by the edition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technical answer: 32,767

Practical answer: much harder and more variables

There is no difference between editions, but performance features as the editions go up can enable your machine to practically support more dbs.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms143432.aspx

Comment: @ahsan - Yes, that is correct, but express limits your hardware so that no matter the machine size, only 1 CPU core and up to 1 GB of RAM is used.

Answer (score 1):

there are four editions mainly (Express, Web, Standard, Enterprise),it support upto 524PB size except express edition(which is support 10GB).first create one database and see the size of that based on that calculate the no.of databases that particular edition support it.:)
for more:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms143432.aspx

Comment: Your link clearly says, maximum number of databases per instance is 32,767.  Max number of databases does not have anything to do with max database size.

Comment: ya but,,,when you are going to maintain large companies data it may be consider!!!

Comment: In general, possibly, but that is not what the OP asked for.